# Unable to convert string into date in tMap component Talend

Tags: etl, talend

I have gone through some similar questions but those solutions didn't worked for me I am having a date field which is String of timestamp `"1631898440"` I tried converting this string into date using tMap but got this error - `java.lang.RuntimeException: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "1631898440"`.

The function I am using -

```
row5.mydatecolumn!=null && !"".equalsIgnoreCase(row5.mydatecolumn)? TalendDate.parseDateLocale("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", row5.mydatecolumn, "EN") :null
```

Also tried -

```
TalendDate.parseDate("ddMMyyyy",row5.mydatecolumn)
```

In this I am getting this err- `timestamp out of range: "898442-07-16 00:00:00+05:30"ERROR`

How to resolve this issue is there anything wrong with the format of date?

Comment: put a tjava and paste on it this code : String str = "1631898440";
     SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
     Date date = new Date(Long.parseLong(str));
     System.out.println(sf.format(date));

Comment: in advanced settings put this imports       :                                                                  import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.DateFormat ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your user routine  just create a fonction like this :

```java
 public static Date Convert_String_To_Date(String String_Timestamp) {
        
        SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
        Date date = new Date(Long.parseLong(String_Timestamp));
        System.out.println("*** Date Converted to this patter ddMMyyyy : "+sf.format(date));
        return TalendDate.parseDate("ddMMyyyy",sf.format(date)) ; 
    }
```

don't forget the import

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
```

then for me i just put a tjava component where i called my fonction like below

```
String str = "1631898440";
System.out.println(Format_String_Date.Convert_String_To_Date(str)) ;
```

So , in your case you would call this fonction in your tMap like this i guess :

```
row5.mydatecolumn!=null && !"".equalsIgnoreCase(row5.mydatecolumn)? 
Format_String_Date.Convert_String_To_Date(row5.mydatecolumn) :null
```

Here is the output

```
[statistics] connected
*** Date Converted to this patter ddMMyyyy : 19011970
Mon Jan 19 00:00:00 CET 1970
[statistics] disconnected
```

Comment: Thank you it's working, how can I make it in GMT0 in talend?